# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value (Swift, Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When I click the IBAction button I am getting the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" Thread 1:EXC_BAD_Instruction.

The crash occurs on the  **Downloader.sharedDownloader.upClicked(postObject)** line.

I have researched this error, and it seems like the postObject variable is nil and causing the crash. I have read about optionals and tried using an if let statement and a != nil statement, but neither of these suggestions have solved the problem.

I do not understand why the postObject variable returns nil in my TableViewCell but not in my CommentingViewController file

Why is my postObject returning nil in my TableViewCell file and how might I fix it?

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {    

 var number:Int = 0

 var postObject: PFObject!

@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!


@IBOutlet weak var postText: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var counts: UILabel!


@IBAction func upvote(sender: UIButton) {


    number += 1


    counts?.text = "\(number)"




    Downloader.sharedDownloader.upClicked(counts.text!,post: postObject)
    print("success")
   }
```

Here is the file where the postObject variable of the same type is used on the line **Downloader.sharedDownloader.postingAComment(wf_commentingTextView.text, post: postObject)** but does not cause a crash.

```
class CommentingViewController: UIViewController {


var postObject:PFObject!

weak var delegate: CommentingViewControllerDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var wf_commentingTextView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "handlePostingComment:", name: postCommentNotification, object: nil)
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Post", style: .Done, target: self, action: "postComment")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item


}
// post a comment
func postComment(){
    if wf_commentingTextView.text.characters.count > 0{
        Downloader.sharedDownloader.postingAComment(wf_commentingTextView.text, post: postObject)
    }

}

func handlePostingComment(notification: NSNotification){
    if let success = notification.object as? Bool{
        if success {
            delegate?.reloadComments()

        } else{

        }
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
  }
```

Here is the Downloader file where I declared the two functions being compared.

```
     func postingAComment(text:String, post: PFObject){

    let comment = PFObject(className: "Comments")
    comment.setValue(post, forKey:"post")
    comment.setValue(text, forKey:"text")
    comment.setValue(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "fromUser")

    comment.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(postCommentNotification, object: success)
        })


    }

}

func upClicked(text:String,post: PFObject){
    let upVoteObj = PFObject(className: "Upvote")
    upVoteObj.setValue(post, forKey: "post")
    upVoteObj.setValue(text, forKey: "text")
    upVoteObj.setValue(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "fromUser")

    upVoteObj.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(upVoteNotification, object: success)

        })
    }
     print("vote was saved")
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where do you initialize postObject in TableViewCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
 var postObject: PFObject!
```

To

```
var postObject = PFObject(className:"PostObject") //Or whatever you class is
```

Will get it to stop crashing, but you likely want to be passing in postObject, which you're either passing in nil or haven't set cell.postObject in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.